# Migrate sql schema to many databases using Flyway

Tags: java, mysql, flyway, sqlmigrations

I'm trying to write a simple Java sample application which uses Flyway to migrate many databases on one IP. When I run this application it completes without error but nothing seems to happen, the `schema_version` table is not created.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("databaseConfig.xml");
    ClientDAO clientDao = ctx.getBean("clientDao", ClientDAO.class);
    List<String> clients = clientDao.getClients();
    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
    for (String client : clients) {
        flyway.setDataSource("jdbc:mysql://" + STAGE_DB_IP +"/" + client, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        flyway.baseline();
        flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);
        flyway.migrate();

    }
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

The databases already exist with tables.

Comment: Have you checked if clients List has any value?

Comment: Yes. clients List contains names of all databases

Comment: Update: When i comment  flyway.migrate() it start creating me schema_version table....

Comment: Maybe flyway cannot find migration files?

Comment: Few things. 1) Your call to `Flyway.baseline` is redundant, `Flyway.baseLineOnMigrate` will do that for you when calling `Flyway.migrate`.. 2) After `Flyway.migrate` use the `MigrationInfoDumper` with the output of `Flyway.info` to get the state of things. Update the question with that output if that doesn't help you solve it. 3) I don't know what the default schema is on MySQL, but I'd be looking in the equivalent of the `public` schema for `schema_version`

Comment: After a couple of hours i used flyway.setLocations("filesystem:C:/db");
And it started working. The default classpath db/migration was not working.....